# Time.current.tap{|t| t.change hour: 10 } is not working in Rails 4.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-on-rails-4.2, ruby-2.3

I tried

```
[107] pry(main)> t=Time.current
=> Tue, 02 Jul 2019 19:19:05 KST +09:00
[108] pry(main)> t.tap{|tt| tt.change hour: 10 }
=> Tue, 02 Jul 2019 19:19:05 KST +09:00
[109] pry(main)> t
=> Tue, 02 Jul 2019 19:19:05 KST +09:00
```

hour is not changed...

I expect

```
[110] pry(main)> t.tap{|tt| tt.change hour: 10 }
Tue, 02 Jul 2019 10:00:00 KST +09:00
```

Really I want

```
[111] pry(main)> Time.current.tap{|t| t.change(hour: 10, min: t.min)}
Tue, 02 Jul 2019 10:19:00 KST +09:00
```

Answer (score 3):

`change` returns a new time object, so this value is ignored by `tap`. You can use tap's brother, `yield_self` (ruby 2.5+)

```
t.yield_self{|tt| tt.change hour: 10 }
```

Comment: @chobo: it's trivial to look up and steal the implementation. Even writing one yourself should not be too hard :)